# Spring boot : can not read resource bundle .properties files with @Value() annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I had project coded with spring MVC. I switch to spring boot. 
I use code below to set one of resource bundle properties file :

```
@Bean(name = "appConfig")
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource appConfig() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/appConfig");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); 
    return messageSource;
}
```

I run the code and i get error below:

```
Indexing into type 'org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource' is not supported
```

On guy recommended this code :

```
 @Bean(name = "appconfig")
public PropertiesFactoryBean appconfig() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("appConfig.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

and i get this error :

```
Property or field 'appConfig' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have forgottten `/`
in 
 `bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("appConfig.properties"));`

This code worked for me.

```
@Bean(name = "appConfig")
public PropertiesFactoryBean appconfig() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/appConfig.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

:)